# Conversion failed when converting varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select T1.StateId, T1PointId 
from Table1 T1
join Table2 FPMDE on T1.PointId = T2.PointID
where T1StateId = '1'
and T1StateId in (select convert (int, T3.StateName)
                  from Table3 T3 
                  where T1.StateId = T3.StateId and T3.StateName = 'Alabama')
```

I am getting error for the above query. Could you please let me know how to convert varchar value to data type int?

Comment: `select cast (T1StateName as int)` looks suspicious since you can't convert a state name to a number, as does `where T3.StateId = T3.StateId` since that will match _all_ rows.

Comment: is all the data in the varchar column `T1StateName`  of data type int?  if not you can't!

Comment: On 2012+, `TRY_CONVERT(int, T1StateName)`, on lower versions, you could start with `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(T1StateName)=1 THEN 1 END`, but note that `ISNUMERIC()` is far from perfect.

Comment: I have edited the query and tried. But it is showing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your intended query is this:

```
select T1.StateId, T1PointId 
from Table1 T1 join
     Table2 FPMDE
     on T1.PointId = T2.PointID
where T1StateId = 1 and -- guessing that T1StateId is a number
      exists (select 1
              from Table3 T3 
              where T3.StateId = T1StateId and
                    StateName = 'Alabama'
             ) ;
```

Notes:

- You almost have a correlation clause in the original query; I assume you want the state ids to match.
- There is no need for both `in` and the correlation clause in this case.
- For numeric constants, don't use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure this is the problem

```
cast (T1StateName as int)
```

Based on the column names alone I suspect T1StateName has some non integer

try

```
select distinct T1StateName  
from - correctTableName
```

I assume T1StateId is supposed to be T1.StateId

```
select T1.StateId, T1PointId 
  from Table1 T1
  join Table2 FPMDE 
        on T1.PointId = T2.PointID
  join Table3 T3 
        on T3.StateId = T1.StateId   
       and T3.StateName = 'Alabama' 
 where T1.StateId = 1
```

But that makes no sense as unless T1.StateId = 1 is 'Alabama' then you get no rows

And if T1.StateId = 1 is 'Alabama' then you don't need that part at all

Even if T1StateId is a separate column then it would still only return a value if that is Alabama